# Interpolate value at a point using Kriging

Tags: arcpy

Is it possible to use Kriging ,in the spatial analyst toolbox, to interpolate a value at a point(instead of a raster)? If not then how would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The SA kriging tool inputs points, and outputs an interpolated raster. If you are only interested in the value at 1 point, you can use Extract Value to Point tool to assign the interpolated (Kriging) value to the point you are interested in.